# Execute Oracle 11g function from SQL Server with result insert into SQL table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a SSIS package that query data from SQL table (using SQL Task tool) and pass it's output to a ForEach loop container that will insert value into query variable. Within the container is another SQL Task with Oracle connection to execute function in Oracle with the query. Although the package runs very slow, it still produces result. However, I need help on putting the result into a SQL table.

Furthermore, let me know if there are better ways of optimizing the package.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to change the query inside the SSIS package in order to insert 1000 by 1000 instead of 1 by 1. You can play with the numbers taking in consideration the result of the performance.

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  ...
SELECT * FROM dual
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KOBER. Frankly I'm new to SSIS so not sure I can understand your advice. Where do I put the query that you recommended? The first SQL Task has a full result set from SQL query and that result is used as part of building query expression. The second SQL Task within the loop is taking that query expression and execute an Oracle 11g function hence using Oracle connection.

Comment: Hi Kamrul, You could think about a **variable** where you can store the dinamic part of the script, during the loop you need to implement a logic for ranges (IF 1...1000 then the task is going to be execute it), as second alternative you can write into a **temp file** the whole query cos is local will be faster, and finally add it on the second task

Comment: Hi @KOBER. The reason it ran slow was due to incorrect configuration of the SSIS package. I configured an expression on a variable while that same variable expression was also configured on Expression Task tool. That causes the slow and even hangs every time I click on the expression tool.